# Add header and footer to each page from a pdf template

Tags: templates, sweave

I have a document and I would like to include a header and footer to each page.
The header and footer are at the top and bottom of an otherwise blank pdf file which is to be used as a template. Is there a way for me to overlay the header and footer of the pdf with the document?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\begin{document}


\lipsum[1-25]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option using the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package:

[image]

The code (needs two runs for the elements to reach their final locations):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage[scale=1,color=black,angle=0,opacity=1]{background}
\backgroundsetup{
contents={
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[text width=\linewidth,anchor=south,align=center] 
    at ([yshift=1cm]current page.south)
    {This is the footer};
  \node[text width=\linewidth,anchor=south,align=center] 
    at ([yshift=-2cm]current page.north)
    {This is the header};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-25]

\end{document}
```

Using the options for the `\node`s, you can control the desired positioning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package `fancyhdr`.
Put this on the top of your `.tex` file :

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
%pieds et haut de page   
\pagestyle{fancy}  
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}   
\fancyhead[L]{text you want here}    
\fancyhead[R]{text you want here}    
\fancyhead[C]{text you want here}    
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}%if you want to put blackline    
\fancyfoot[L]{\textbf{page \thepage}} % for the numbers of the page     
\fancyfoot[R]{text you want here}    
\fancyfoot[C]{text you want here}  
\begin{document}
```